# How to use a specific line from a file and printing it out in Python

Tags: python

I have a final project. This is the part that is tripping me up. I need to figure out how to pull an entire line out of a file if the last digit is over 750. The file looks like this:

```
A 500 600 700 144.666
```

And then goes as many times as you tell it to, so up to J or Q or F or whatever. If the 4th number is over 750, then I have to print the entire line. The requirements are as follows:

Print an alarm message to screen with X, Y, and Z positions of asteroids within a distance of less than 750 km.

For the nearest asteroid, send an alarm message to the console followed by sound of 7 beeps (actual beep sound).

The alarm message could look like the following: only two digits after the decimal point.

```
Warning  -  Warning  - Warning
Nearest asteroid B at ??, ??, ??: ?? km away 
Time to impact ??? seconds
asteroid B at at ??, ??, ??: ?? km away
asteroid D at at ??, ??, ??: ?? km away
```

I haven't even gotten close to the sound part yet, I just need to figure out how to print an entire line. I'm assuming a for loop or an if statement? It's my first time programming, so i'm a little lost.

Comment: So can you show us a snippet of code and an example file to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("path/to/your_file") as f:
    for line in f: # loop over every line
        spl = line.split()
        if float(spl[4]) > 750:# split on whitespace and check if fourth/last digit is > 750
            print(line)
        else:
            print("Alarm! asteroid within 750km, position {} {} {}".format(spl[1],spl[2],spl[3]))
In [4]: line  = "A 500 600 700 144.666"

In [5]: line.split() # splits into individual elements
Out[5]: ['A', '500', '600', '700', '144.666']

In [6]: float(line.split()[4]) # casts the string to a float
Out[6]: 144.666
```

You must cast to a `float` as `int('144.666')` will throw an error, also `750.1 > 750`

If you are on windows you can use [winsound](http://pyglet.org/) for the alarm

[1](http://pyglet.org/): https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html or [pyglet](http://pyglet.org/)  seems cross platform

Comment: It's telling me that the 's',which I replaced with my file, doesn't have any attributes. I also tried to place the list that I use to append to my file as 's' and it said the same thing. :(

Comment: @Jackie. it should be line not s, that was a typo, make sure you supply the full path to your file if you are not in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' '):
        if int(row[4]) > 750:
            print(' '.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you read the file like this

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        ##split the line by your deliminator (assumming it is tab delimitated), this will return a list 
        fields = line.split('\t')
        ### determine if fields[4] which correspond to the 5th column (python list are 0 based) 
        if (int(fields[4]) > 750) 
            print(line)
```